# Compare two lists (values) and geht True/False back

Tags: python, list, compare

I would like to solve a problem in Nodebox3 with a piece of python code. It's a missing feature in Nodebox 3. Here is my question:

I would like to compare the values of two different list and create than a new output list. The new List should have the details from List 1 and List 2 and the result of the compare process. (True or False)

The numbers in List1 and List2 exist once on the list, but it's possible that they are unsorted and in different places (index) on each list with every load.

[My idea Compare Lists and Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyJ4m.jpg)

```
Values List 1 (Master): App1 
1
2
3
4
5

Values List 2 (Compare to List 1): App2
2
4

Output (list with Header):
App1    App2    CompareResult   
1       0       False
2       2       True    
3       0       False 
4       4       True 
5       0       False
```

I tried to create some code on my own, but I'm new to programming, and it gives me not the result back, I'm looking for. It only shows me the matching numbers.And that's all. Maybe somebody has an idea how I get the wrong result.

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6REs0.jpg)

```
def matches_out(list1, list2):
    set1 = set(list1)
    set2 = set(list2)
    # set3 contains all items common to set1 and set2
    set3 = set1.intersection(set2)
    #return matches
    found = []
    for match in set3:
        found.append(match)
    return found
```

If somebody has an idea, thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi for us to help you faster we need to see the code that you are working on so we can debug it together.  Cheers

Comment: Please _paste_ all relevant code into the question. Do not link to third-party sites.

Comment: If you post an image of your code, you are expecting us to rewrite everything in order to help you. Why not paste your code in the question to make it easier? Was it really easier to take a screenshot and upload than to copy-paste text?

Comment: Sorry, newbie error to the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the intersection of the two lists is correct, but only half the solution, because it finds only the matches. You also want to report the mismatches, and for that you need the union of the two lists as well.

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [2,4]
matches = set(list1).intersection(list2)
candidates = set(list1).union(list2)
result1 = []  # 1st column of output
result2 = []  # 2nd column of output
for c in sorted(candidates):
    result1.append(c if c in list1 else 0)
    result2.append(c if c in list2 else 0)
for i in range(len(result1)): 
    print ("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t".format(result1[i], result2[i], result1[i]==result2[i]))
```

That produces this output:

```
1   0   False   
2   2   True    
3   0   False   
4   4   True    
5   0   False
```

It's not clear what you want to happen if the same number appears more than once in a list. Your code ignores duplicates so I have followed the same line.

I'll leave adding the headings up to you.

*Edit*: fixed cut'n'paste error reported by OP.

Comment: Dear BoarGules. Many thanks for your solution and help. I see it works with a small modification "{0". I try now to use it for the implementation into Nodebox 3. Great job and thank you! Rgs Andy